# Find string position in url and replace url

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say that i'm currently on:

```
http://example.com/page/1/foo/something/here
```

So what I need to do, is to search for window.location.href for a specific string, in this case "foo", and I need to url before the string foo, so in this case will be

```
http://example.com/page/1/
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways. Here is the shortest:

```
'http://example.com/page/1/foo/something/here'.split('foo')[0]
```